# Does "en" always carry roughly the same meaning as "in", or might it need to be paraphrased?

Tags: traduction, grammaire, anglais

In many French sentences, the word "en" seems to be directly translatable as "in", for example:

> Je habite en France. (I live **in** France)
>
> On peut parler en japonais. (One can speak **in** Japanese)

However there seem to be some cases where a complete paraphrasing is needed.  For example, using "in" as a replacement here makes no sense:

> Tu en as trop. (You have too much of it)
>
> Je voudrais en savoir plus. (I'd like to know more about it)

Can "in" be used in these sentences somehow instead of needing paraphrasing?  In what circumstances does "en" carry a different meaning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"En" can have different functions:

**adverbe**:  indicates the origine

> Il en vient / He comes from there

**préposition**: indicates a location, a situation, a form, a transformation, a duration, a mean

> J'y vais en train / I go by train

Or it can be a gérondif, placed before a verbe : en mangeant, en jouant.

> Il buvait sa bière tout en jouant du piano / He was drinking his beer while playing piano.

**pronom personnel**:  De ce, de cela, de lui, d'elle, d'eux, d'elles

> Tu n'en sais rien / You know nothing about it

Answer (score 4):

Both are different words: one is a preposition, while the other is a pronoun. Looking at the [definition of *en*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en), you'll notice two tabs: *EN<sup>1</sup>, prép.* (preposition) and *EN<sup>2</sup>, pron. atone de la 3e pers.* (3rd person pronoun).

Only the preposition can adequately be translated by "in"; you should be able to infer easily from the context whether it's a preposition or not.